# Remove required variation price from WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a WooCommerce shop from scratch and I encountered the following problem:

The products on this shop all have variations but always have the same price. I'm controlling the price by using a custom field (ACF) and I'm not making use of the standard WooCommerce fields (title, price, description, image etc). The only thing I'm using is the variation module.

WooCommerce requires me to fill in a price for each variation and when not filled in it will show "This product is out of stock" on the front page.

Is it possible to use the variations but without the (required) price for each individual variation, and use my custom price field instead? Or atleast remove the variation prices so that my product won't show "Out of stock" when no variation price is filled in?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: It's a general question, not code related ;) I'm just asking if it's possible to get around or not, lol.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for remove variable price. Add code in to functions.php file

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html','custom_from',10);
add_filter('woocommerce_grouped_price_html','custom_from',10);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html','custom_from',10);
function custom_from($price){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This controls the front end right? The front end is not the problem, the problem is that the backend of a product requires me to enter a price for each variation. If I don't enter these, the product will show out of stock since WooCommerce checks for the prices on variations to determine if it's available or not.

Thanks for the effort though